# Edited one page in my working menu and now all menu buttons don't open unless I right-click and open in new tab

Tags: menus, buttons, tabs

I just recently edited a page on my site and changed the page in my main menu, however now all of my menu buttons don't work unless I right-click and open in a new tab...then the page appears. I have disabled all plug-ins and nothing seems to change. I have also cleared all cache from site and browser, as well as used other browsers. Has anyone else ran into this problem?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
        at Function.globalEval (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
        at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (ajax.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1)
        at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
        at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
        at slideInNewPage (ajax.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1)
        at d (ajax.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1)
        at Object.success (ajax.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1)
        at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

Comment: But that error normally means you're getting an HTML error page rather than the script. Can you use your browser's debug tools network tab to look at the response you're actually getting instead of the script? Hopefully there's a useful error message there.

Comment: Hi, I was looking into that and was unable to figure that out exactly. No error messages were coming up for the error above, only for the yellow warnings. I am having a developer take a look and will post back here if I get an answer and what happened. After over 20 hours trying to figure it out hopefully someone will be able to get my site back on track! Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error won't be in the console, it'll be in the network tab in the file that this is trying to load (if you can identify which one this is). What's happening is that jQuery is trying to loading and run file that it thinks is a JavaScript file, but it actually an HTML file being served by an endpoint that should be returning a script. Have a look at all of the file there for error codes, or you'll have to find one that looks like it's supposed be loading a script but the 'response' tab shows HTML content.

Comment: Thank you, taking a look now.